# Uvicorn + Quart yielding error 413 on post request

Tags: python, httpserver, uvicorn, quart, http-status-code-413

I'm trying to setup a simple http server to receive ( potentially large ) JSON objects.

```
from quart import Quart, request
import uvicorn

app = Quart(__name__)

@app.route( '/' , methods=[ 'POST' ] )
async def hello():
    json = await request.json
    return ('',204)


config = uvicorn.Config( app, host="127.0.0.1", port=8000, ws_max_size=2**64, h11_max_incomplete_event_size=2**64,  )
server = uvicorn.Server( config )
server.run()
```

however when I test this using the following

```
import requests
requests.post("http://127.0.0.1:8000/", json = {"test":"0"*(2**32)})
```

I get `"POST / HTTP/1.1" 413 Request Entity Too Large`

But I can't seem to figure out where this is coming from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can adjust the [MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH](https://github.com/pallets/quart/blob/8a0cdd5a650c29d036dfec3000818b0e06ce3e0c/src/quart/config.py#L19) configuration setting to up this limit.